# JS function for adding image to all randomly generated text from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that inserts a randomly chosen word from an existing array into a `div`. I figured this thing out and now I need to insert an image at the end of every word generated after pressing a button. Any ideas? thanks!

```js
var words = function() {
  var wordsArray = new Array('Sun', 'Door', 'Table', 'Moon', 'Sky', 'Chair');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
    var newWords = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
    document.getElementById('wordhere').innerText = newWords;
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="generate-button" onclick="words();">generate!</button>
<div class="title h4" id="wordhere"></div>
```

Comment: What did you try to solve that?

Comment: Given that you've solved part 1 (inserting/adding the words), where did you get stuck implementing part 2?

Comment: i didnt try anything because i dont even know what to do, exactly

Comment: Is the image to be randomly chosen too? Have you got a selection of images stored in your web application or something? When you say you donl't know what to do...in terms of what? How to display an image in a web page? How to select an image, or something else?

Comment: thanks for a complete question and please forgive me if a do things wrong here, im new on this community. 1 - one image across whole array of words. 2 - i've got it in my vscode project folder. 3 - i dont know how to insert a specific image at the end of the word generated using JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you can replace the statement with:

```
document.getElementById("wordhere").innerHTML = `${newWords}<img src = "path">`
```

Basically you can write any node inside that template literal